# Passing variables (day, month and year as integers) between existing forms C# (Windows forms app)

Tags: c#

I'm quite new in c#.
What I'm doing is a simulator in which you can order production - I've already succesfuly created a class that specifies the order. This class I made in separate form (usercontrol) which displays on form1 after clicking certain button on menu strip.
In the form1(Main) there is a groupbox which contains textbox in which actual day,month and year is displayed thanks to three variables day, month and year.
What I need to do is to pass these variables to the user_control form in which the class is implemented.

This is the code and implementaion of date variables:

```
//#######**Form1.cs**#########
int day;
int month;
int year;
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(((month==1) || (month==3) || (month==5) || (month==7) || (month==8) || (month==10) || (month==12)) && (day==31) )
            {
                if(month==12)
                {
                    day = 1;
                    month = 1;
                    year = year + 1;
                    Date_txtbox.Text = "0" + day + "." + "0" + month + "." + year;

                }
                else
                {
                    day = 1;
                    month = month + 1;
                    if (month <= 9)
                    {
                        Date_txtbox.Text = "0" + day + "." + "0" + month + "." + year;
                    }
                    else if (month > 9)
                    {
                        Date_txtbox.Text = "0" + day + "." + month + "." + year;
                    }
                }
                
            }else if(((month == 4) || (month == 6) || (month == 9) || (month == 11)) && (day == 30))
            {
                day = 1;
                month = month + 1;

                if (month <= 9)
                {
                    Date_txtbox.Text = "0" + day + "." + "0" + month + "." + year;
                }
                else if (month > 9)
                {
                    Date_txtbox.Text = "0" + day + "." + month + "." + year;
                }
            }
            else if ((month == 2) && (day == 28))
            {
                day = 1;
                month = month + 1;
                Date_txtbox.Text ="0" + day + "." + month + "." + year;
            }
            else
            {
                day++;
                if (day <= 9)
                {
                    if (month <= 9)
                    {
                        Date_txtbox.Text = "0" + day + "." + "0" + month + "." + year;
                    }
                    else if (month > 9)
                    {
                        Date_txtbox.Text = "0" + day + "." + month + "." + year;
                    }

                }
                else if (day > 9)
                {
                    if (month <= 9)
                    {
                        Date_txtbox.Text = day + "." + "0" + month + "." + year;
                    }
                    else if (month > 9)
                    {
                        Date_txtbox.Text = day + "." + month + "." + year;
                    }
                }
            }

            
        }
```

What I need to do is to pass the following variables: day, month, year to the class which specifies the order that is in another form(usercontrol).

Below is the implementation of the clas:

```
//#########Production_usercontrol.cs#########
public class production_ordered
    {
        public string production_time_obj; // A <= I've set this as a string only for testing purposes, when I'm done with this it wil be changed integer, so for now do not bother yourself with it if it does not make a sense to you
        public int par_quan; // B
        public int lin_quan; //C
        public string type; //D
        public int ID_prd;

        public void Ordered_prd(string A, int B, int C, string D, int ID)
        {
            
            this.production_time_obj = A;
            this.par_quan = B;
            this.lin_quan = C;
            this.type = D;
            this.ID_prd = ID;
            
        }
       
    }
.
.
.
     public void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//#######################################################################################
            string a = production_time;

            bool ol;
            int b;
            ol = int.TryParse(Parallel_quantity.Text, out b );

            bool rec;
            int c;
            rec = int.TryParse(Linear_quantity.Text, out c ) ;


            string d = checkedItemText;
            id++;

            production_ordered prod= new production_ordered();
            prod.Ordered_prd(a, b, c, d, id);
    //#####################################################
    .
    .
    .
    }
```

How to do this?

Any help will be apreciated because I'm stuck.

Comment: Could be a weird question but why not use DateTime Type. It already have a way to handle date and it already suport format for display. and the whole thing dispear into a variable and one line of code.

Comment: So you're creating an instance of the `production_ordered` UserControl at run-time (from a menu click) and displaying that on your main form?  You need to reference that specific instance so that you can call its `Ordered_prd()` method and pass the data.  Are you creating only ONE instance of the UserControl?...or many?  I'm guessing one.  If so, move the declaration of that variable from local scope up to class/form scope so that you can reference it and pass the data.  Show us the code that creates the UserControl and we can help.